# Angular2 Not working for templateUrl

Tags: angular

While I'm embeding code into the `template` tag the code is working fine and shows content.

If I move the content to `templateUrl` the console shows the particular page not found.

[image: 404]

## home.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent{

}
```

## tsconfig.js

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false
 }
}
```

How could I overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a  Plunker?

Comment: also check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

Comment: Can you post what you have in your `@Component`, please?

Comment: Please see the question is updated

Comment: Can you post the entry point of you app? ie. index.html, and is that in the same directory as your component?

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this issue by adding `module.id` on the @Component directives, Because I have configured my module as commonjs so the commonjs module need the moduleId attribute on @Component directives.

## why we need commonjs module

To use urls relative to the component file, your project must be a commonjs module (set "module":"commonjs" in tsconfig), and you have to include module.id in your component decorators:[1]

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'home',
   templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent{

}
```